# AlwaysOn with TDE

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, transparent-data-encryption

Recently, I setup an availability group with 3 nodes. The 2 synchronous nodes are on the same domain, "domain 1". The third asynchronous (DR) node is on a different domain, "domain 2". I have a new requirement, to encrypt all databases using TDE on the third (DR) node only. Will this be possible?

I'm assuming that it is possible, but I want to ask your expert opinion and what will be the impact of this setup?

Comment: What database are you using?  Did you mean to tag this "SQL Server" (a database engine) rather than "SQL" (a programming language)?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU2 to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

The secondary databases are just "clones" of the primary, so you cannot enable it on just one node.

The way to do it is actually to enable encryption on the primary, then it will replicate by itself if all is well (if you copied the certificate on the secondary nodes).

However, you should really look into [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510178(v=sql.110).aspx) and practice in a virtual lab before doing anything on production. It could be easy to get into an otherwise avoidable situation.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, this is really appreciated. Actually, I already sent my recommendation yesterday to the management that it's not advisable to encrypt just the DR NODE base on microsoft practice. But, your answer give me peace of mind and really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. By the way, you could probably [enable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(v=sql.100).aspx#_Toc189384690) [Bitlocker](http://mssqltrek.com/2011/08/30/sql-server-encryption-part1/) on the DR node, but it would have a different effect.

Comment: Yup, but I think it is not recommended using AlwaysOn. It is possible if the setup is shared clustered "all drives" because I believe bitlocker use to encrypt drive and volume level.. Again, thanks Bogdan for this reply...